# Python bottle static file not applying CSS

Tags: python, css, bottle, static-files

So I am making a python bottle website and trying to apply CSS to a page with static file.
But it is not applying even though it works for all other routes.
The link in html is the same as all others and in inspect there is no error to see.

```
@get('/add/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
@get('/view/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
@get('/edit/<filename:re:.*\.css>')
@get('/<filename>')
def staticCSS(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='views/css/')
```

This works for all routes except `/edit/<username>/<title>` I do not know what could cause this at all.

Comment: "This works for all routes except" isn't specific enough. _How_ does it not work? (E.g. 404? 500?) Please provide the output you expect and the output you're observing, so we can try to help.

Comment: There is no error in the inspect no trace of me even adding a link in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are over complicating the static file method.  I find the easiest thing to do is this:

```
@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='/static')
```

This makes everything from the folder `static` accessible via a direct link.  This is far easier to manage, since you can use any kind of nested sub folder structure under static that you want.

Comment: This hasn't done anything to help my problem I had it like this before but it hadn't changed anything.

Comment: You can't link your CSS like `<link href="/static/edit/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Or like  `<link href="/static/{{variable}}/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: my link is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="tacit.css">` as the folder is `/views/css/tacit.css`

Comment: why not explicitly say `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/view/css/tacit.css">`

Comment: Or if you want it dynamic using the template system and fill in a variable like `dynamic_route` :  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/{{dynamic_route}}/css/tacit.css">`